# Detect that text number is too large to convert to Int in swift

Tags: c++, swift

I have a program written in C++ and I’m trying to create another program written in Swift that has the same functionality. One thing the C++ code can do is when given a text string that contains a numeric value that is too large to convert to an integer, the program can detect and report that issue. So, given C++ code like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        auto value = std::stoi("999999999999999999999999999");
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
        std::cerr << "The value is too large to convert to an integer.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How could someone write an equivalent program in Swift that can detect the same condition?

Comment: Hint: [`Int.init?(_ description: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2927504-init) is a *failable* initializer.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, we use an initializer to create an integer form a `String`. This initializer returns `nil` if it can't create an `Int` from it. So you can *optional bind* it to a new variable and see if it can do it or not and do the needed work accordingly:

```
let value = "999999999999999999999999999"

if let number = Int(value) {
    print(number)
} else {
    print("The value is too large to convert to an integer")
}
```

---

#### FYI

In `Foundation` there is a type called `Decimal` that can handle this value and more epic numbers.

```
if let number = Decimal(string: text) {
    print(number)
} else {
    print("Probably it's not a number at all!")
}
```

Also you can check if the text contains only decimal digits (using Foundation):

```
text.trimmingCharacters(in: .decimalDigits).isEmpty
```

So merging together:

```
if let number = Int(text) {
    print(number)
} else if !text.trimmingCharacters(in: .decimalDigits).isEmpty {
    print("It's not a number!")
} else if let decimal = Decimal(string: text) {
    print("The value \(decimal) is too large to convert to an integer")
} else {
    assertionFailure("What else could be prevent us from creating an integer? That happened!")
}
```

Comment: I am aware of the initializer for Int that can convert text to an integer. The thing about that initializer is that it can fail for a number of reasons, not just because the text contained a number that was too large. I specifically want to know that the text was just too large to convert. The C++ code written can detect that. The Int initialer cannot. I want to know how someone can detect that particular condition.

Comment: Can you use `foundation` or not?

Comment: I should be able to use Foundation

Comment: Problem:
let value = Int(“123xyz”) // returns nil.  However
let value = Decimal(“123xyz”) // returns a decimal value set to 123.  
123xzy is not a number that is out of range. It is an invalid number and so the wrong error would detected.

Comment: @TronThomas this line `!text.trimmingCharacters(in: .decimalDigits).isEmpty` is for that. Isn't it enough?

Comment: I misunderstood the check. I thought it was checking to see if the text was empty overall. Apply that check does prevent the problem.